# "upgrade model from database" in Entity Framework designer doesn't update nullable for column

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I created an edmx from a database. A column had NOT Null property. The I changed it to allowing nulls. Every time I select "upgrade model from database.." in the edmx designer, the nullable property for that column always stays as false. I have to change it manually.

Is this a bug in the designer in VS 2010?

Comment: Michael9000's answer is correct and works: Delete the table in edmx-designer, and add it again in "Update model from database".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug. See [this bug report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/45101c23-591d-4a34-80cf-9aaae7b1176e/) plus answer on social.msdn

Answer (score 1):

Delete the table in edmx-designer, and add it again in "Update model from database".